# Google Sheets: Pulling data from tab 2 to tab 1 based on a drop down variable from tab 1

Tags: google-sheets

Sheet reference I'm currently working with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UxwkzBTnwOLV341Vciy8_NWylMSSjhb7SkFDqVW6ImI/edit?usp=sharing

So, kinda what the title says.. I'm completely stumped here.

Trying to pull the data (including the column headers) over from tab 2 into tab 1 based on the drop down (grey colored) menu item chosen by the user in tab 1.  *(The "potions" are listed in column A of Tab 2 as well, row 1 indicates "herbs" required for any particular potion by the variable numbers in the corresponding cells for the "potions")*

Essentially, you choose a "potion" in the grey drop down, then a "recipe list" will populate in the remaining white space in tab 1.

Any ideas here?

Comment: You could do it with an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula in cell B12:

```
=transpose(filter(transpose(filter('Recipe Data'!B:BJ,(row('Recipe Data'!A:A)=1)+('Recipe Data'!A:A=B9))),len(transpose(filter('Recipe Data'!B:BJ,('Recipe Data'!A:A=B9))))))
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for!  Kishan and JPV, you are great!  <3

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kishan's contribution, you can also try

```
=transpose(query(transpose({'Recipe Data'!B1:BJ1; filter('Recipe Data'!B2:BJ, 'Recipe Data'!A2:A=B9)}), "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, JPV!  Works great!